# Memory Leak in Pytorch Autograd of WGAN-GP

Tags: memory, neural-network, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network, autograd

I want to use WGAN-GP, and when I run the code, it gives me an error:

```
def calculate_gradient_penalty(real_images, fake_images):

    t = torch.rand(real_images.size(0), 1, 1, 1).to(real_images.device)
    t = t.expand(real_images.size())

    interpolates = t * real_images + (1 - t) * fake_images
    interpolates.requires_grad_(True)

    disc_interpolates = D(interpolates)

    grad = torch.autograd.grad(
        outputs=disc_interpolates, inputs=interpolates,
        grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(disc_interpolates),
        create_graph=True, retain_graph=True, allow_unused=True)[0]

    grad_norm = torch.norm(torch.flatten(grad, start_dim=1), dim=1)
    loss_gp = torch.mean((grad_norm - 1) ** 2) * lambda_term

    return loss_gp
```

> RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/tensor.py in
> backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs)
> 243                 create_graph=create_graph,
> 244                 inputs=inputs)
> --> 245         torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs=inputs)
> 246
> 247     def register_hook(self, hook):
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/autograd/**init**.py in
> backward(tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph,
> grad_variables, inputs)
> 143         retain_graph = create_graph
> 144
> --> 145     Variable.*execution_engine.run_backward(
> 146         tensors, grad_tensors*, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs,
> 147         allow_unreachable=True, accumulate_grad=True)  # allow_unreachable flag
>
> RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 64.00 MiB (GPU 2;
> 15.75 GiB total capacity; 13.76 GiB already allocated; 2.75 MiB free; 14.50 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)

The train code:

```
%%time

d_progress = []
d_fake_progress = []
d_real_progress = []
penalty = []
g_progress = []

data = get_infinite_batches(benign_data_loader)
one = torch.FloatTensor([1]).to(device) 
mone = (one * -1).to(device) 

for g_iter in range(generator_iters):

    print('----------G Iter-{}----------'.format(g_iter+1))

    for p in D.parameters():
        p.requires_grad = True # This is by Default
    
    d_loss_real = 0
    d_loss_fake = 0
    Wasserstein_D = 0

    for d_iter in range(critic_iter):
        D.zero_grad()
         
        images = data.__next__()
        if images.size()[0] != batch_size:
            continue
    
        # Train Discriminator
        # Real Images
        images = images.to(device)
        z = torch.randn(batch_size, 100, 1, 1).to(device)
        d_loss_real = D(images)
        d_loss_real = d_loss_real.mean(0).view(1)
        d_loss_real.backward(mone)
    
        # Fake Images
        fake_images = G(z)
        d_loss_fake = D(fake_images)
        d_loss_fake = d_loss_fake.mean(0).view(1)
        d_loss_fake.backward(one)
    
        # Calculate Penalty
        gradient_penalty = calculate_gradient_penalty(images.data, fake_images.data)
        gradient_penalty.backward()
    
        # Total Loss
        d_loss = d_loss_fake - d_loss_real + gradient_penalty
        Wasserstein_D = d_loss_real - d_loss_fake
        d_optimizer.step()
        print(f'D Iter:{d_iter+1}/{critic_iter} Loss:{d_loss.detach().cpu().numpy()}')
    
        time.sleep(0.1)
        d_progress.append(d_loss) # Store Loss
        d_fake_progress.append(d_loss_fake)
        d_real_progress.append(d_loss_real)
        penalty.append(gradient_penalty)

    # Generator Updata
    for p in D.parameters():
        p.requires_grad = False  # Avoid Computation

    # Train Generator
    # Compute with Fake
    G.zero_grad()
    z = torch.randn(batch_size, 100, 1, 1).to(device)
    fake_images = G(z)
    g_loss = D(fake_images)
    g_loss = g_loss.mean().mean(0).view(1)
    g_loss.backward(one)
    # g_cost = -g_loss
    g_optimizer.step()
    print(f'G Iter:{g_iter+1}/{generator_iters} Loss:{g_loss.detach().cpu().numpy()}')
    
    g_progress.append(g_loss) # Store Loss
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you need to retain the graph when computing `grad`? Are you expecting to back propagate on `loss_gp` afterwards?

Comment: I think yes, if I set it as False, it occurs: RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time, but the saved intermediate results have already been freed. Specify retain_graph=True when calling .backward() or autograd.grad() the first time. And the gradient (of the GP part of loss) need to backpropagate through entire D network

Comment: Then you simply don't have enough memory on your device. Can you show the part where you backpropagate from `loss_gp`?

Comment: Sure, I had uploaded the train code.

Comment: Yes, you are going to need more memory. Else you will have to either reduce your batch size or reduce your model's input size.

Comment: Will bath size influence it? Cause the memory usage increase every epoch, afraid that no matter how much memory I have, it will run out sooner or later...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All loss tensors which are saved outside of the optimization cycle (*i.e.* outside the `for g_iter in range(generator_iters)` loop) need to be detached from the graph. Otherwise, you are keeping all previous computation graphs in memory.

As such, you should detach anything that gets appended to `d_progress`, `d_fake_progress`, `d_real_progress`, `penalty`, and `g_progress`.

You can do so by converting the tensor to a scalar value with [`torch.Tensor.item`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.item.html), the graph will free itself on the following iteration. Change the following lines:

```
    d_progress.append(d_loss) # Store Loss
    d_fake_progress.append(d_loss_fake)
    d_real_progress.append(d_loss_real)
    penalty.append(gradient_penalty)

#######

g_progress.append(g_loss) # Store Loss
```

to:

```
    d_progress.append(d_loss.item()) # Store Loss
    d_fake_progress.append(d_loss_fake.item())
    d_real_progress.append(d_loss_real.item())
    penalty.append(gradient_penalty.item())

#######

g_progress.append(g_loss.item()) # Store Loss
```